# vim autocomplete for pymongo

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, pymongo

How can I setup vim & pymongo autocomplete for the code below:

```
import pymongo

connection = pymongo.Connection()
collection = connection["msg"].posts
result = collection.<tab>
```

Autocomplete in general works but it doesn't seem to be contextual, it just shows everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Pydiction](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=850) for vim. Although I have not tried it with third party modules, the documentation says it should work:

'Pydiction can complete Python's keywords, built-in functions, and string literals, as well as standard, **custom and third-party package and module names and their attributes and methods**. It can also complete fully-qualified names such as "module.submodule.method", as well as non-fully qualified names such as simply "method".'